# Vitest loads cjs export of dependency instead of esm

Tags: javascript, vite, es6-modules, commonjs, vitest

I have a `node_modules` package that exports

```
"main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
"module": "dist/esm/index.js",
"types": "dist/types/index.d.ts"
```

Where the `cjs` export had been built with `tsc --module commonjs` and the `esm` export has been built with `tsc --module esnext`

The consumer app is set as `"type": "module"`

Now, `vite` correctly loads the `dist/esm/` export of the package, but `vitest` loads the `dist/cjs/` export.

This causes issues with the tests, that I can resolve if for example I manually edit the `package.json` of the package to `"main": "dist/esm/index.js"`

Why does this happen and is it possible to force `vitest` to consume the `esm` export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer to the question can be found here https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/discussions/4233 straight from the vitest's maintainers themselves.